# What am I missing in the concept of matrix and transform

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, internet-explorer-10

Evaluating some code i thougt that

```
     var elcube = document.getElementById("cube");
     var matrixcube = MSCSSMatrix(elcubestart.style.transform);              
     matrixcube = matrixcube.translate(0, 0, -150);
     matrixcube = matrixcube.rotate(0, 90, 0);
     elcube.style.transform = matrixcube;
```

is the same as

```
    var elcube = document.getElementById("cube");
    elcube.style.transform = "translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg)";
```

but it isnt.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: I can't grasp the difference between the two codeblocks, so I mis something I think in understanding the code.

Comment: Can you explain how it's different?